# Serve images/assests using Slim framework

Tags: php, image

I need to serve images which are common in multiple modules, to the `resources` folder us outside of public folder. I am using Slim Framework.

```
app/-
    -Classes/
    -vendor/
    -Resources/-
               - Images/
    -Admin/-
           - Styles/
           - Scripts
           - index.php
           - init.php
    -Public/-
            - Styles/
            - Scripts
            - index.php
            - init.php
```

Currently I have created a subdomain static.pro1.local/ to serve local images. But now I am in search for some other way.

On slim I am trying to make a route to dynamically create and serve images as required

```
$app->get('/assets/:height/:width/:id/:type', function() use ($app) {
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    $dir = dirname(__DIR__)."/Resources/Images/";
    $image = new Imagick($dir.$id.'.svg');
    /*
        Code to create images based on height, width, and change its format {svg to png} as required
    */
        $app->response->header('Content-Type', 'content-type: image/'.$type );
        echo $image;
    // $res->body($image);
});
```

I intent to use it as `<img src="/assets/200/400/test/png" />` But i keep getting 404 error.

I already tried

- http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/questions/93-how-get-image-for-a-specific-route
- http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/questions/674-best-practice-to-return-images
- http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/questions/359-file-download
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20439144/php-how-to-use-a-rest-controller-to-serve-images

and few other. 
I also found https://github.com/tuupola/slim-image-resize but I need to use SVG Conversions and few other stuffs which it does not have.

Answer (score 10):

I guess you are on the right track but you are missing some points.
I made a fresh install of slim ("slim/slim": "^2.6"). This is my directory structure.

```
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── public
│   ├── .htaccess
│   └── index.php
├── Resources
│   └── Images
│       └── smoke.svg
└── vendor
```

This is my Slim application file, index.php. Btw I didn't spend time on re-sizing the image I leave that to you.
The application contains the `assets` route and `test-image` route.

```
<?php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/assets/:height/:width/:id/:type', function($height, $width, $id, $type) use ($app) {
    $dir = dirname(__DIR__)."/Resources/Images/";

    $im = new Imagick();
    $im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
    $svg = file_get_contents($dir.$id.'.svg');
    $im->readImageBlob($svg);

    $im->setImageFormat("png32");
    $im->resizeImage($height,$width,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);

     $app->response->header('Content-Type', 'content-type: image/'.$type );
     echo $im;
     $im->destroy();
     
});

$app->get('/test-image', function() use ($app) {
    echo '<img src="assets/100/200/smoke/png" />';
});

$app->run();
```

The trick is removing the index.php from the url with the help of .htaccess
There is a section for url rewriting in the docs; http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/rewrite/ -The docs include nginx directives too.-

The content of the .htacess file is;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Also you need to add `AllowOverride` section to your virtual host file to be able to use the directives in your .htacess file. This one goes to virtualhost.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/PUBLIC_DIRECTORY">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Don't forget to restart or reload apache.

Then browse to `http://<virtualhost>/test-image` it should be good to go.

## Update:

After your comments I setup a docker instance with nginx installed.

This is my virtualhost config file.

```
server {
server_name default;
root        /var/www/default/public;
index       index.php;

client_max_body_size 100M;
fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;

location / {
      try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
}

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
  expires       max;
  log_not_found off;
  access_log    off;
}

  location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }
 }
```

And changed the php code a little bit to use correct url for the image generator route. I named the route and used `urlFor` method to retrieve correct url generated by the framework itself.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/assets/:height/:width/:id/:type', function($height, $width, $id, $type) use ($app) {
    $dir = dirname(__DIR__)."/Resources/Images/";

    $im = new Imagick();
    $im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
    $svg = file_get_contents($dir.$id.'.svg');
    $im->readImageBlob($svg);

    $im->setImageFormat("png32");
    $im->resizeImage($height,$width,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);

     $app->response->header('Content-Type', 'content-type: image/'.$type );
     echo $im;
     $im->destroy();
     
})->name('generate-image');

$app->get('/test-image', function() use ($app) {

    $imageUrl = $app->urlFor('generate-image', 
                              array('height' => '200',
                                    'width' => '200', 
                                    'id' => 'smoke',
                                    'type' => 'png')
                            );

    echo '<img src="'.$imageUrl.'" />';
});

$app->run();
```

When I browse to the `http://localhost/test-image` url everything looks perfect on my side.

[image]

Comment: This is not really an answer. You are just stating the basics of slim app. I know slim, I am working on it. The above technique of returning image is similar to one of the links I mentioned above. It does not work.  I tried your code to just to assure myself. It does not return image.

Comment: Hi @AbhinavKulshreshtha yes the answer was very basic. It looks like I didn't get the question or the question isn't clear enough. What do you mean with returning an image? What I understand is outputting image data to the browser with necessary headers. If you are seeing 404 It may not be about slim/php code you are writing. Maybe you have to check your web server setup/error logs/access logs etc. If you can explain your problem a bit clearer we can find a solution. Also what web server are you using?

Comment: Nginx , but tested on Apache also. I intent to use it as `<img src="/assets/200/400/test/png" />`  i.e usually we set the relative folder path to the assets. But I want to set a router which gives me the image.  I am setting the proper headers. I am really confused on why it is showing error 404. Slim logs is also not making any sense.

Comment: @AbhinavKulshreshtha I have update the answer, check and see if there's an improvement on your side.

Comment: A strange behaviour.  It seems that when I have more than 3 rest attribute, I need to add a trailing slash.  Not only yours, but a few of my older attempts works when I add trailing slash. I reported it on slim issues, But they can't reproduce it.  What is your server configuration? Yours seems to work without trailing slash.

Comment: Hi @AbhinavKulshreshtha it looks pretty strange. Here is my configuration;
`PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2015 15:23:08)`, `slim/slim: ^2.6`,  `nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)`, built the configuration on docker container this is the kernel version `3.14.5-031405-generic`. I hope it helps.

Comment: Mine is same, except i use fedora, But that does not Effect.  My Discussion on https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/1471 doesn't help much either.  I am starting to think it has to do something with my nginx config. But that config file is what slim docs provide.  I can replicate issue on Nginx and apache. But it does not exists on PHP's inbuilt server.   Anyways, Thanks for all your time.

Comment: I see, it is really strange. If I were you I would breakdown slims router code via xdebug or simple echoes it's opensource anyhow. I would try to find the correct lines when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without changing the main configuration.
Let's put the images into the '/static/' directory.

Then change the index.php file (let's suppose it's in '/public/'), if we would like to serve (with special header) these image files; put these lines somewhere to the top:

```
$s=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$e=substr($s,-4 );
if ((substr($s,0,8)=='/static/') &&
   (($e=='.gif') || ($e=='.png') || ($e=='.jpg'))
   ) { if (!file_exists(htmlentities('../'.$s))) { exit('No such file.');
       } else {header("Content-type: image/".($e=='.jpg'?'jpeg':substr($e,1)));
       readfile(htmlentities('../'.$s)); exit();
       }
}
```